# how to loop the selectbox options using angularstrap

Tags: angularjs

I have selectbox with options, but how to loop through the options using angularstrap,

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="status" data-ng-change="">
    <option value="cheque">Cheque No</option>
    <option value="stat">Status</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller add the options array object and use ng-options for the select. You can see [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects#selects) for more details.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" ng-change="change()" ng-model="status" data-html="1" ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" bs-select>
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.status = '';
   $scope.options = [
    {value: 'Cheque', label: 'Cheque'},
    {value: 'Status', label: 'Status'}
  ];

  $scope.change = function(){
    console.log('changed to : '+$scope.status);
  };
});
```

[Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldIj6A65f7ofKi7mKmjc?p=preview)